# how to adapt the size of JSF component inside a div

Tags: html, templates, jsf-2, primefaces

I am developing a JSF project with primefaces framework and i made this layout with some html divs and css.

Here is my body divs:

```
        <h:body>
        <div id="homeContainer">
            <div id="header"  class="greenBorder">
                 <h1 class="h1">
              <ui:insert name="homeHeader"/>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="line" />
            <div id="west" class="greenBorder">
                <ui:insert name="westMenu" />
            </div>
            <div id="center" class="greenBorder">
                <ui:insert name="content" />
            </div>
            <div id="east" class="greenBorder"/>
            <div id="footer" class="greenBorder" />
        </div>
    </h:body>
```

[image: my layout]

When i insert menu, the component is bigger than my west div. How i can put my menu with to adapt his size based on west div??

Answer (score 0):

hy,
you can put a  like this:

```
<h:body>
    <div id="homeContainer">
        <div id="header"  class="greenBorder">
             <h1 class="h1">
          <ui:insert name="homeHeader"/>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div id="line" />
        <div id="west" class="greenBorder">
          <p:scrollPanel style="width:850px;height:auto" mode="native">
            <ui:insert name="westMenu" />
          </p:scrollPanel>
        </div>
        <div id="center" class="greenBorder">
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </div>
        <div id="east" class="greenBorder"/>
        <div id="footer" class="greenBorder" />
    </div>
</h:body>
```

modify the style :)